# Can I ask non-technical questions on Game Development?

Tags: discussion

For example, this Indie game Domina, if I was developing this game, I would need to think of how this game would end, e.g. would there be a final boss?

Can I ask this kind of non-technical questions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Questions, like "should there be a final boss?" can't be asked on the main site, because it's too broad. However, if you include additional details (e.g. Would it make the game feel more finished if I added a separate end-boss instead of ending the game after the player finished off the boss of the last level?), then it might work. Questions like this go into [game-design](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-design).

Comment: I recommend [checking out the guidance on the `game-design` tag wiki](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/tags/game-design/info) - through past meta discussions we've tried to boil down what ingredients help make a focused, on-topic [tag:game-design] question.

Answer (score 4):

Non-technical (e.g., non-programming) questions are *absolutely* on-topic here.

They are subject to the same guidelines for broadness or subjectivity that technical questions are, however, so take care when asking that you're focusing on something that can be reasonably answered objectively with arguments that cite evidence or facts.